# Using midpoint circle algorithm to generate points of a filled circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, geometry

I need to generate and store the coordinates of each point of a filled circle of say, radius 10 in Javascript.

It seems like the best way to do this would be to use the [midpoint circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm), but I'm not sure how to adapt it to find every point in the circle. The coordinates are going to be stored as objects in an array.

Could someone help me with the implementation?

Comment: It doesn't make sense what you are trying to do ultimately... Are you trying to draw a circle? ASCII art?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I think it would probably be faster in this case to test all pixels in the bounding box for their distance to the center. If `<= r` then the point is in the circle and should be pushed onto your array.

```
function distance(p1, p2)
{
   dx = p2.x - p1.x; dx *= dx;
   dy = p2.y - p1.y; dy *= dy;
   return Math.sqrt( dx + dy );
}

function getPoints(x, y, r)
{
    var ret = [];
    for (var j=x-r; j<=x+r; j++)
       for (var k=y-r; k<=y+r; k++)
           if (distance({x:j,y:k},{x:x,y:y}) <= r) ret.push({x:j,y:k});
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You loop through all the possible points and you run the Point-In-Circle check on them.

Something like the following would suffice...

```
var result = [];
var d = 10;
var r = d / 2;
var rr = r*r;
for(var y=0; y<d; y++)
 for(var x=0; x<d; x++)
  if((x-r)*(x-r)+(y-r)*(y-r) < rr)
   result.push({"x": x, "y": y});
```

Modifying the above algorithm to handle other (more complex) shapes/path/polygons would be difficult. For a more generic solution you could use HTML5 CANVAS. You create a canvas, get the 2d context draw all of your shapes/paths/polygons in solid black then iterate through the pixel data and find the pixels with an alpha channel greater than 0 (or 127 if you want to alleviate false positives from anti-aliasing).

```
var r = 5; // radius of bounding circle
//
// set up a canvas element
//
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = r*2;
canvas.height = r*2;
canvas.style.width = (r*2) + "px";
canvas.style.height = (r*2) + "px";
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
//
// draw your shapes/paths/polys here
//
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(r, r, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
//
// process the pixel data
//
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,(r*2),(r*2));
var data = imageData.data;
var result = [];
var str = "";
for(var y = 0; y<(r*2); y++) {
    for(var x = 0; x<(r*2); x++) {
        var pixelOffset = (y * (r*2) + x) * 4;
        if(data[pixelOffset+3] > 127) {
            result.push({x: x, y: y});
            str += "(" + x + ", " + y + ") "; // debug
        }
    }
}
//
// debug/test output
//
document.body.innerHTML += str;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
alert(result.length);
```